# How to fetch the corresponding row details if it matches certain string in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, macos, excel

I am taking the value from Shankar_demo spread sheet and checking in the A column if that value is present in env_cred tab. If it matches I want to get the other column values corresponds to the matched record. Could you please help.

```
abc = Sheets("shankar_demo").Cells(15, 4)
Debug.Print abc
For Each env_val In Sheets("Env_Cred").Range("A1:A3").Value
If abc = env_val Then
i = 1
Else
i = i + 0
End If
Next env_val
Debug.Print i
If i = 0 Then
MsgBox "Error:Credentail details could not be fecthed for the given environment, Please check env_cred spreadsheet tab"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code logic little bit. See if it helps your situation.

```
Dim abc
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Long: i = 0
abc = Sheets("shankar_demo").Cells(15, 4).Value
Debug.Print abc
For Each cel In Sheets("Env_Cred").Range("A1:A3")
    If abc = cel.Value Then
        i = 1
    End If
Next cel
Debug.Print i
If i = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error:Credentail details could not be fecthed for the given environment, Please check env_cred spreadsheet tab"
End If
```

For what it is worth, the same can be achieved with a formula like VLOOKUP(except messagebox).